# REST "POST" method with Lotus Script

Tags: web-services, rest, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

so I got a project to send a file via REST to a specific end point using Lotus Script from IBM Domino Server. I successfully connected to the endpoint with "POST" option and selected the required content type (text/csv) and I'm receiving a response.

The issue I am having is that I can't send a string through and I don't know what's the problem.
Other side has some crappy admin that doesn't understand any of my questions and ALL info he gave me is URL & Content Type.

Here is the code to connect/select options:

```
Dim httpObject As Variant
Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Call httpObject.setOption( 2, 13056)
Call httpObject.open("POST", myUrl, False)
Call httpObject.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv")
```

Now to send the data to the other side I have to use this:

```
Call httpObject.send(mystring)
```

Yet it doesn't work and gives me an error for that line: The parameter is incorrect.
However, and I am not sure if it actually works since the admin on the other side doesn't know
how to check it, when I try to send pure text instead of string I don't get any errors and it seems like the code executes without issues.
Even if that method works it's not an option since I have dynamic data that I need to send so can anyone help if you've seen this issue before OR similar. Couldn't find a solution on the internet.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "pure text instead of string". Try adding the length of your content "mystring" to the request...`xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(mystring)`

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner but I managed to fix a problem. Not sure why and how but when I do 'Call httpObject.sent(CStr(mystring))' it works...and by "pure text" I mean: "This is my string", and by string I mean Dim mystring As String, mystring = "This is my string"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the `Content-Length` header that defines how large the data is that you are sending as the body of the request.

```
xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(mystring)
```

Without knowing what the server is doing, it's obviously hard to say for sure what's going on. You will need the Admin person to send you a copy of their server logs.